# Observable member missing from 'rxjs/observable'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I create a new Angular project like this:

```
 ng new ecommerce
```

All works as expected until I attempt this:

```
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
```

There is an observable folder under 'node_modules/rxjs' with lots of files but the Observable member is conspicuously missing and the compile attempt crashes.

I've tried everything I can think of.  Can you help me to understand and to fix?

Thank you - Dale

Comment: can you post your rxjs version

Comment: >> If rxjs is version above 6
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; <<

Brilliant!  This fixed the problem I reported but unfortunately added a new problem.

My code reads: 

import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

…
return Observable.of(this.products);

The error reads:

Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

I can also remove the /add from the import since of.js exists on both folders.  But this returns the same error.

I don't understand this at all.  Can someone advise? 

Thank you - Dale

Comment: You need to import { of } from 'rxjs';

Answer (score 2):

In rxjs version 6, Import `Observable` in this way,

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Package.json file. Check the rxjs.

```
 **"rxjs": "^6.3.3",**
```

If rxjs is version  below 6

```
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
```

If rxjs is version  above 6

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow this Steps:-

1. Install Dependancy of [rxjs-compat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compat)

   `npm install --save rxjs-compat`
2. Add in your Application.

   `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`